# Proof check regarding a simple real analysis problem about the intersections of sets

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Good day to everyone, can you please provide feedback on my personal attempt to prove this simple statement (a problem from Rudin's Principles of Math Analysis)?

Let **A** be the set of real numbers *x* such that $0 < \mathit{x} \leq 1$. For every $\mathit{x} \in \mathbf{A}$ let $\mathbf{E}_x$ be the set of real numbers *y*  such that $0 < \mathit{y} < \mathit{x}$. Then the intersection $\bigcap_{x \in A} \mathbf{E}_{x}$ is empty.

My proof (by contradiction):
Assume the intersection is not empty. That means at least one y exists which belongs to every $\mathbf{E}_{x}$. Since it belongs to every $\mathbf{E}_{x}$, obviously y has to be the smallest possible real number within **A** (if there was some x for which $y > x$, then y would not be a common element for every possible $\mathbf{E}_{x}$). 0 is the infimum of **A**. If y is the smallest element and $0 < y$, 0 is clearly not the infimum, which contradicts our definition and finishes the proof.

Please point out any flaws in my reasoning, I am trying to get back to understanding solid mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea.  Maybe say that $y\le x,\,\forall x\in A$, instead of "$y$ is obviously the least element in A", since $A$ has no least element.

Direct proof:

Let $y\in A$. Then $\frac y2\in A$ and $0\lt \frac y2\lt y$. Thus $y\not\in E_{\frac y2}$.  Thus $y\not\in\bigcap_{x\in A} E_x$.  Thus $\bigcap_{x\in A} E_x=\emptyset$.